# vmware fusion port forward between vms

Tags: linux, windows-7, portforwarding, vmware-fusion

I am running two vms:

One is a linux webserver
The other is windows 7 used for testing purposes

I can easily forward traffic from my host machine to the webserver using the vmnet8/nat.conf configs.

I need localhost web traffic on the windows vm to go to my linux vm, but nothing is apparent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the network cards on both VMs on bridge. Then both VMs can see each other like classic network :)

Comment: When I set to bridged, I loose internet connectivity, I am guessing there is some extra configurations that need to go into setting this up?

Comment: You need to configure your vm on your network. I guess you use ActiveDirectory and a domain, then you must put your vms into the domain.

Comment: I see. I switch networks quite a bit though and will be on some that I do not have permissions to configure. I did find though that while in the windows vm I could enter the ip address of my host and it would pick up on it just fine.